# How to use groupBy and zip in real practice?

Tags: haskell, zip, combinators

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List(nub, groupBy)

z = splitOn "+" "x^2+2*x^3+x^2"

y = map (splitOn "*") z

x = map head y

toInt :: [String] -> [Int]
toInt = map read

u1 = filter ((< 2) . length) y
u2 = filter ((> 1) . length) y

v = map ("1" :) u1

q = u2 ++ v
q2 = zip toInt(map head q) (map last q)
q6 = groupBy nub(map tail q) q
q3 = map tail q
q5 = nub(q3)

q1 = map head q
```

1. For

```
zip toInt(map head q) (map last q)
```

I would like to add back the head to the tail after convert head into integer
result should be `[[1,"x^3"],[2,"x^2"],[1,"x^2"]]`

I can do

```
*Main Data.List> zip [2,1,1] ["x^3","x^2","x^2"]
[(2,"x^3"),(1,"x^2"),(1,"x^2")]
```

but above can not, and there is a difference I noticed is, this is `()`, not `[]`

2. How to write `groupBy` on a list, I have passed distinct elements for `groupBy`
After grouping, it is for adding their head

```
groupBy (nub(map tail q)) q
```

:1:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a0 -> Bool'
                with actual type`[a1]'
    In the return type of a call of `nub'
    In the first argument of`groupBy', namely `(nub (map tail q))'
    In the expression: groupBy (nub (map tail q)) q

q is like a hash table, it seems that it can not group by second element

Comment: `[[1,"x^3"],[2,"x^2"],[1,"x^2"]]` is impossible in Haskell: You can't mix different types in a list, but here the inner lists contain both Ints and Strings. The usual solution for this is to use a tuple. Another solution would be heterogenous lists, but I guess that would be over-the-top here.

Comment: it can, the result is [(1, "a"),(2, "b")]

Comment: In Haskell `()` denote tuples, `[]` denote lists, and both are fundamentally different. If you understand this, then please change your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue is that `zip toInt(map q) (map last q)` isn't getting parsed the way you think it is.

Unlike languages with C-style syntax, haskell parses the above as

```
 zip toInt (map head q) (map last q)
```

(Note the space).

That is, it's not applying `toInt` to the result of `map head q` the way you want it to.  Instead, it's attempting to do `zip toInt (map head q)`, which will give you a type error, since you're zipping a function and a list.

What you want instead is

```
 zip (toInt (map head q)) (map last q)
```

Or slightly more succinctly

```
 zip (toInt $ map head q) (map last q)
```

As for your second issue, you're having a similar issue with syntax.  Also, the first argument to `groupBy` needs to be a function that determines equality for the purposes of creating groups.

Comment: after added a bracket, i try second question, can this writing style group by second element?

Comment: Your issue with the `groupBy (nub(map tail q)) q` is that `groupBy` takes a function argument, which you're not giving it.

Comment: does you mean i should write groupBy (=nub(map tail q)) q